# not able to configure the xdebug to the Netbeans

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, xdebug

I have configured the xdebug to the Netbeans IDE. My machine has been installed with XAMPP 1.7.4. it has php 5.3.5.

( In phpinfo() page i noticed,

Apache Version - Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4
  Debug Build - no 
)

The version of xdebug is "php_xdebug-2.1.1-5.3-vc9.dll".
I kept this dll under the folder(directory) C\:xampp\php\ext.

And I done the settings in the file php.ini, under the folder --\php\php.ini.

I have done the folloing setting in the file php.ini

```
zend_extension_ts="C:xamppphpextphp_xdebug-2.1.1-5.3-vc9.dll"

;xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:xampptmp"
```

Later I tried to debug the php project.. debugger is not working. But in the IDE "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)" message is getting.

I request you to current me.

Comment: Is xdebug visible in the output from phpinfo()?

Comment: in the output of the phpinfo(), I noticed "Debug Build  no"

Comment: If it doesn't explicitly have an xdebug section near the bottom, the extension hasn't loaded. Double check you have the right version for your PHP binary.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Uncomment remote_enable=true**, it is necessary
2. **Enable xdebug.remote_log**, e.g. xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log", it should tell you if xdebug attempts to connect to the IDE or not
3. **If it doesn't attempt to connect**, put an xdebug_break() call in your code, this should force the call to the IDE

Also note that you have to define an env variable to debug from CLI, and for browsers there are many extensions. Details on: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: Which php.ini file I should choos to configure ? Either under the directory 'apache\bin' or '\php\'.

Comment: To find out what php.ini file you should use, call phpinfo() from the php instance that you want to debug. It should show the path to the effective php.ini